Cloning project in Azure DevOps
I am trying to clone a project from one organization to another in Azure DevOps. We’ve been able to successfully clone within one org, but when we use same steps to clone between two organizations, it does not work. Could you help with process steps please?
We tried to use same steps as we use when cloning project with one org. However, we get message on the screen that either link is not correct or password is not correct fo multiple attempts

please follow the doc for a check, i added the detail checkpoints below. Thanks.

Cloning a Git Repository is NOT cloning an Azure DevOps project.. the latter would involve high fidelity copies of Work Items, all of the Dashboards, The Wiki(s), the Pipeline(s), the Artifacts, and a few other things...
To the best of my knowledge all solutions for this are commercial [not free]
